# How to return an zip file from Foxx- arangodb?

Tags: zip, arangodb, foxx

The premise is that I want to return a zip file from foxx endpoint.
The endpoint would:

-Take a string and put it inside a file

-Return the zip from the response

After some research, it seems not possible due to various reason. I want to make sure my understanding is correct and whether there is an workable solutions:

Approach 1: Using amd-zip module from npm

- There is an error return from performing an simple zip with a string which is `zlib.deflateSync() is undefined`. I think it is due to V8 context and nodejs are not the the same.

Approach 2 : Using Jszip-sync: More browser based library.

- This one will run without an error, but it always return empty
  result. Testing suggest the sync wrapper does not seemed to work in
  foxx environment

Approach 3: Using zip function from arango built-in file

- But as the official document stated, this seems like an extremely bad
  idea (write file to system, zip it, read back and return inside foxx
  handler)